# Xamarin.iOS release mode error: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

HELP!!! In my iOS Xamarin app, debug mode works for me, but in release mode, app crashes on startup and I found this two logs:

```
HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
```

---

```
Can't get most elevated app state from dictionary {
BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx";
SBApplicationStateKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 900;
SBApplicationStateRunningReasonsKey =     (
            {
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx";
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 4;
    },
            {
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = Resume;
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
    }
);}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

Have a try with uninstalling the app from the emulator, cleaning and rebuilding to check whether it works .

**In addition** , Xamarin iOS when release mode ,need to **Enable debugging** .

Follow this steps : ***iOS properties -> iOS Debug - > Enable debugging***

[image]